# Correct way of adding to a list from cell array in matlab?

Tags: matlab, syntax, cell-array

I'm writing  some code to split up a 180x2 matlab cell array based on a string in the second column. This string is one of EP,GA,PS,SS or SA. In python I could define empty lists then use conditionals to iterate over the elements of the list and append them to the relevant lists.

The Code

```
EP=[];
GA=[];
PS=[];
SA=[];
SS=[];
for i=1:size(d),
    if strcmp(d(i,2),'EP'),
        append(EP,d(i,1))
    elseif strcmp(d(i,2),'GA'),
        append(GA,i)
    elseif strcmp(d(i,2),'PS'),
        append(PS,i)
    elseif strcmp(d(i,2),'SA'),
        append(SA,i)
    elseif strcmp(d(i,2),'SS'),
        append(SS,i)
    end
end
```

Note that 'd' is a 180x2 cell array that I copied and pasted into matlab rather than import. The general structure of the data however is:

```
12.9089000000000    'EP'
13.3697000000000    'SA'
13.4335000000000    'EP'
13.5302000000000    'PS'
13.8434000000000    'EP'
14.2583000000000    'EP'
14.8221000000000    'GA'
```

However when attempting this tactic in matlab I get an error:

```
Error using append (line 38)
Wrong number of input arguments for obsolete
matrix-based syntax.

Error in Boxplot_All_results (line 12)
        append(GA,i)
```

Could somebody tell me the correct way of doing this in matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please not that `d` is a cell array. To index the elements of a cell array, use `{}`. If you index using `()` like you did, you end up with a small cell array containing only the indexed element(s).

To append in Matlab you basically have two choices:

```
%concatenate the list with a scalar. Also suitable for two lists.
EP=[EP,d{i,1}] %could also be done using cat
%append to the end
EP(end+1)=d{i,1}
```

While this fixes the problem, I recommend to implement it on a more generic way:

```
names={'EP','GA','PS','SA','SS'}
s=struct()
for idx=1:numel(names)
    s.(names{idx})=[d{strcmpi(d(:,2),names{idx}),1}]
end
```

You end up with a struct containing the data you want.

Comment: Nice touch the structure. +1. (_but there is a typo: capital `S` then small `s` in the loop_)

Answer (score 1):

Can you show MatLab code?
How do you append those values to cell array?

You can just create one `a = {}`
and then append element at the `size+1` index. That operation extends your cell array.

Or you can also do a trick like that: `a = [a; {value}]`

Answer (score 0):

To append elements to a cell array, a correct syntax would be:

```
for i=1:size(d),
    if strcmp(d(i,2),'EP'),
        EP = [EP ; d(i,1) ] ; %// append(EP,d(i,1))
    elseif strcmp(d(i,2),'GA'),
        GA = [GA ; d(i,1) ] ; %// append(GA,i)
```

but there are more ways, as you can read in the documentation: [Add Cells to a Cell Array](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-cells-to-a-cell-array.html)

---

There are also more ways to build your final extracted arrays in one assignment instead of having them growing dynamically (*mLint will complain about that by the way*).

Get the indices of the elements which satisfy your condition then create an array with only the matching elements. For example:

```
iEP = cellfun( @(c) strcmp(c,'EP') , d(:,2) ) ; %// logical array of indexes where the condition is true
EP = d(iEP,1) ;                                 %// Create "EP" in one assignment - EP is a [cell] array
```

If you only have numeric values to retrieve in these new variables, may be having a `double` array instead of a `cell` array will be convenient :

```
iGA = cellfun( @(c) strcmp(c,'GA') , d(:,2) ) ; %// logical array of indexes where the condition is true
GA = cell2mat( d(iGA,1) ) ;                     %// Create "GA" in one assignment - GA is a [double] array
```

Of course you can bypass the intermediate variable holding the indices:

```
PS = d( cellfun(@(c)strcmp(c,'PS'),d(:,2)),1) ;           %// Create "PS" in one assignment [cell] array
SA = cell2mat(d(cellfun(@(c)strcmp(c,'SA'),d(:,2)),1)) ;  %// Create "SA" in one assignment [double] array
```